# Retrofit2 HTTP Get Json to RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

I am trying to use Retrofit2 to retrieve data as JSON and then parsing it to my RecyclerView adapter, but whatever I do I can't figure out how to get this thing to work.

At the moment, I can load up one RecyclerView with local DBFlow data, but can't figure out how to do it for the JSON that I HTTP GET with Retrofit2 for my second RecyclerView. I have the code below so far, which loads the JSON in the Log. But can't parse it to the RecyclerView.

MainActivity.java:

```
onCreate() {
...
   mGithubApi = ApiUtils.getApi();
   mGithubRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) 
   findViewById(R.id.github_repository_recyclerview);
   RecyclerView.LayoutManager mGithubLayoutManager = new 
   LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
   mGithubRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mGithubLayoutManager);
   mGithubRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
...
   loadGithubUserRepositoryJson();
}

// Load Github repo JSON
public void loadGithubUserRepositoryJson() {
    Call<ResponseBody> result = api.getRepos("motivecodex");
    result.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            try {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, response.body().string());

                mGithubAdapter = new GithubRepositoriesAdapter((List<GithubRepository>) mGithubRepository);
                mGithubRecyclerView.setAdapter(mGithubAdapter);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "error loading from API");
        }
    });
}
```

GithubRepositoryAdapter.java

```
public class GithubRepositoriesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GithubRepositoriesAdapter.RepositoryViewHolder> {

    private List<GithubRepository> githubRepositoryList;

    public class RepositoryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView repository, commits, stars, forks;

        public RepositoryViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            repository = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listitem_repository);
            commits = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listitem_commits);
            stars = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listitem_stars);
            forks = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listitem_forked);
        }
    }

    public GithubRepositoriesAdapter(List<GithubRepository> githubRepositoryList) {
        this.githubRepositoryList = githubRepositoryList;
    }

    @Override
    public RepositoryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.listitem_repository, parent, false);

        return new RepositoryViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RepositoryViewHolder holder, int position) {
        GithubRepository githubRepository = githubRepositoryList.get(position);
        holder.repository.setText(githubRepository.getName());
        holder.commits.setText(githubRepository.getStargazersCount());
        holder.stars.setText(githubRepository.getStargazersCount());
        holder.forks.setText(githubRepository.getForks());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return githubRepositoryList.size();
    }
}
```

interface Api.java:

```
@GET("users/{user}/repos")
Call<List<GithubRepository>> listRepos(@Path("user") String user);
```

model GithubRepository.java

```
public class GithubRepository {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("full_name")
    @Expose
    private String fullName;

    @SerializedName("stargazers_count")
    @Expose
    private Integer stargazersCount;

    @SerializedName("forks")
    @Expose
    private Integer forks;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public Integer getStargazersCount() {
        return stargazersCount;
    }

    public void setStargazersCount(Integer stargazersCount) {
        this.stargazersCount = stargazersCount;
    }

    public Integer getForks() {
        return forks;
    }

    public void setForks(Integer forks) {
        this.forks = forks;
    }
}
```

ApiUtil.java

```
public static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.github.com/users/";
public static Api getApi() {
   return RetrofitClient.getClient(BASE_URL).create(Api.class);
}
```

RetrofitClient.java

```
public class RetrofitClient {
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of Log (this approximately as I can't see your types):

```
localRepositoryList.addAll(response.body());
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

P.S: I assume you have in the code something like:

```
GithubRepositoriesAdapter adapter=new GithubRepositoriesAdapter(localRepositoryList);
mGithubRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Another option** in log place:

```
mGithubRecyclerView.setAdapter(new GithubRepositoriesAdapter(response.body()));
```

UPDATE:

```
public void loadGithubUserRepositoryJson() {
    api.listRepos("motivecodex").enqueue(new Callback<List<GithubRepository>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<GithubRepository>> call, Response<List<GithubRepository>> response) {
        try {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, response.body().string());

            mGithubAdapter = new GithubRepositoriesAdapter(response.body());
            mGithubRecyclerView.setAdapter(mGithubAdapter);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<GithubRepository>> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "error loading from API");
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry, had some mismatch of code in my question. I have updated some fields. Can you please look again? With the ''another option'' I get the error: 

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
                                                                                       at com.motivecodex.githubusers.adapter.GithubRepositoriesAdapter.getItemCount(GithubRepositoriesAdapter.java:62)` which is at `return githubRepositoryList.size();`

Comment: mGithubAdapter = new GithubRepositoriesAdapter((List<GithubRepository>) response.body());

Also make sure you get list with data in response.body()... and not null

Comment: All ResponseBody in ENQUEUE shoudl be List<ResponseBody>. Change it in 4 places.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156222/discussion-between-motivecodex-and-shmuel).